# Read Layout InnerHtml into view using jQuery, MVC3

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, view, load, innerhtml

I'm using ASP.NET MVC 3,

I've a `AdminController` and `EditLayout` action.

**What i need is:**
When I request a `/Admin/EditLayout` I need to load the InnerHtml of a Layout stored in `/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml` into a TextArea of the view EditLayout

How to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here's something you can start with...

In the `EditLayout` action you can fetch the `/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml` view as a partial view and using jquery you can dump the html generated into the textArea.

See this article : [Asp.net mvc razor render partial view using jquery Ajax](http://mazharkaunain.blogspot.in/2011/04/aspnet-mvc-render-partial-view-using.html)